# Get Parent of Gtk Submenu

Tags: python, gtk

Calling `get_parent()` on a Gtk submenu (item) does not yield its parent menu but rather the object it extends from. Is it possible to identify the parent menu?

I need it for a much more complex menu structure than the one below MCVE, in order to toggle the RadioMenuItem checkboxes of the above-lying menuitems.

```
menu = Gtk.Menu()
menu_item = Gtk.MenuItem('blah', 'blah')
menu_item.set_submenu(create_submenu())
menu.append(menu_item)

def create_submenu():
   submenu = Gtk.Menu()
   submenu_item = Gtk.MenuItem('blah', 'blah')
   submenu.connect('activate', do_something)
   submenu.append(submenu_item)
   return submenu

def do_something(widget):
   widget.get_parent().set_label('this is not the parent menu') # <--- refers to Gtk.Window, not our menu above
```

Comment: You haven't even added `submenu` to the GUI yet, so it doesn't have a parent. What's interesting is that it returns a Window object instead of `None`...

Comment: I believe that's what happens when I do `menu.append(menu_item)`.

Comment: Well yes, but you call `get_parent()` before that...

Comment: I guess my MCVE was too quick and dirty. let me amend

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. `Gtk.Menu().get_parent()` seems to always return a `Gtk.Window` instance, even if you haven't created a window.

Comment: Ha ok. I'll report it. Thanks

Comment: Reported here https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/issues/160

Comment: The native libgtk3 function which gives the parent menu (or maybe menu-item) is `gtk_menu_get_attach_widget`. In PyGtk3 see the`get_attach_widget()` method https://people.debian.org/~osamu/gtk3tutor/python-gtk3/Gtk.Menu.get_attach_widget.page

Comment: Hi @EdouardThiel, thanks, running `get_parent().get_attach_widget()` on a `Gtk.MenuItem` indeed seems to work.

Comment: Please write and accept an answer, so that other users know that the question has been answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Edouard Thiel, you can indeed run `submenu.get_parent().get_attach_widget()` to receive a reference to the parent menu. More info at [https://people.debian.org/~osamu/gtk3tutor/python-gtk3/Gtk.Menu.get_attach_widget.page](https://people.debian.org/%7Eosamu/gtk3tutor/python-gtk3/Gtk.Menu.get_attach_widget.page)